# I can't pass information to my nodejs server from the html form

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, forms

I created an event that takes information from the form that was supposed to pass information to the node server but after clicking the register button, in the browser console it says 'POST http://127.0.0.1:3000/user/register 400 (Bad Request)
(anonymous) @ register:128)'.

The Html form with a javascript event listener:

```
<title>Register</title>

<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!--===============================================================================================-->  
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="../assets/images/icons/favicon.ico"/>
    <!--===============================================================================================-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!--===============================================================================================-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/fonts/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/vendor/animate/animate.css">
    <!--===============================================================================================-->  
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/vendor/css-hamburgers/hamburgers.min.css">
    <!--===============================================================================================-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/vendor/select2/select2.min.css">
    <!--===============================================================================================-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/css/util.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/css/main.css">
    <!--===============================================================================================-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="limiter">
            <div class="container-login100">
                <div class="wrap-login100">
                    <div class="login100-pic js-tilt" data-tilt>
                        <img src="../assets/images/img-01.png" alt="IMG">
                    </div>
        
                    <form class="login100-form validate-form">
                        <span class="login100-form-title">
                            Register
                        </span>
        
        <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "Valid username is required!!!">
                        <input class="input100" type="text" name="user" placeholder="Username">
                            <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                            <span class="symbol-input100">
                            <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </span>
                        </div>
        
          <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "Valid email is required!!!">
                            <input class="input100" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                            <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                            <span class="symbol-input100">
                            <i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </span>
                        </div>
        
                <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "Password is required">
                <input class="input100" type="password" name="pass1" placeholder="Enter Password">
                            <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                            <span class="symbol-input100">
                            <i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </span>
                        </div>
        
        <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "Valid password is required!!!">
              <input class="input100" type="password" name="pass2" placeholder="Confirm Password">
                            <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                            <span class="symbol-input100">
                            <i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="username error">

                        </div>

                        <div class="email error">

                        </div>

                        <div class="password error">

                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
                            <button name="submit" class="login100-form-btn">
                                Register
                            </button>
                        </div>
        
                        <div class="text-center p-t-12">
                            <span class="txt1">
                                Have an account? 
                            </span>
                            <a class="txt2" href="/user/login">
                                Login
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--===============================================================================================-->  
        <script src="../assets/vendor/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <!--===============================================================================================-->
            <script src="../assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/popper.js"></script>
            <script src="../assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <!--===============================================================================================-->
            <script src="../assets/vendor/select2/select2.min.js"></script>
        <!--===============================================================================================-->
            <script src="../assets/vendor/tilt/tilt.jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script>
                $('.js-tilt').tilt({
                    scale: 1.1
                })
            </script>
        <!--===============================================================================================-->
            <script src="../assets/js/main.js"></script>

            <script>
                const form = document.querySelector('form');
                form.addEventListener('submit', async (e) => {
                    e.preventDefault();

                    const username = form.user.value;
                    const email = form.email.value;
                    const password = form .pass1.value;

                    try {
                        const result = await fetch('/user/register', {
                            method: 'POST',
                            body: JSON.stringify({ username, email, password }),
                            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
                        });
                    }
                    catch (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                })
            </script>
    </body>
```

The node server seems to be working fine but it's just to pass the required information to the server that's the issue. The register controller for post and get request:

```
const register_get = (req, res) => {
    res.render('register')
}

const register_post = async (req, res) => {
    const { username, email, password } = req.body;

    try {
        const user = await User.create({ username, email, password });
        res.status(201).json({ errors });
    } 
    catch (err) {
        const errors = handleErrors(err);
        res.status(400).json({ errors });
    }
}
```

The error handling function:

```
const handleErrors = (err) => {
    let errors = { username: '', email: '', password: '' }

    if (err.code === 11000) {
        errors.email = 'Email has been registered already. Kindly Login in!';
        return errors;
    }

    if(err.message.includes('user validation failed')) {
        Object.values(err.errors).ForEach(({ properties }) => {
            errors[properties.path] = properties.message;
        });
    }

    return errors;
}
```

Comment: Please add more details ... like, what happens if you do a console log on the server post handler showing what the username, email and password are like? Are you using express? Are you allowing json bodies with bodyParser or express?

Comment: From what you've posted, the server is getting the request, encountering an error, returning the "errors" (unless they are undefined in the "try" block) and your frontend is getting the errors (with code 400, which you don't check). Your handler returns the errors to some caller. Why not log the errors or add a breakpoint in the handler and see what they say?

Comment: @devnull69 I tried it and its not showing any errors. But all its telling me is 400 bad request in the browser console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Updated from my comment once I realized handleErrors was on the server side].

From what you've posted, the server is getting the request, encountering an error (probably an undefined "errors" variable in the try block), and then returning the `errors` generated by handleErrors() (which are likely all empty) back to your frontend with code 400, which you see.

(By the way: In the handler you can replace the `let errors =` with `const errors =` if you like. Javascript lets you change values within a `const` as long as the variable itself isn't reassigned.)

EDIT TO ADD -- EXAMPLE:

```
const User = {
        create: async function(o) {},
};
const Res = {
        status: function(c) { return this; },
        json: function(o) { console.log( "json: ", o ); },
};
const register_post = async (req, res) => {
    const { username, email, password } = req.body;

    try {
        const user = await User.create({ username, email, password });
        res.status(201).json({ errors });
    }
    catch (err) {
        const errors = err;
        res.status(400).json({ errors });
    }
}

const p = register_post({body:{username:"U",email:"E",password:"P"}}, Res);
```

When I run this, I get this result:

> json:  {   errors: ReferenceError: errors is not defined
> at register_post (/tmp/t.js:13:32) }

Comment: Its not working. When following the error in the browser console, it takes me to the try block. I'm thinking it's not receiving the values from the frontend

Comment: I don't understand how the browser is taking you to code on the server, but if you are breaking inside the try{} block, you can easily look at req or req.body to see what the values are.  I'll update my answer to clarify what I'm referring to.

Comment: I've seen the problem!!!

Comment: Please accept my answer if it helped. Thanks.